# Change button properties in main form from class

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I would like to ask how I can change buttons properties in main form from class.
I have form with `button called Call`. This button is **disabled**.
I have class which is checking network connection. When is my program connected **I want enabled button Call** from class network but I can't change properties from this class.

**Code**

```
public class network
{
...
MainForm frm = new MainForm();
..
.
.
  if(isNetwork==true)
   {
    frm.Call.Enabled = true;  //nothing happends, button is still disabled
     methodUpdate();  // second solution with calling method, but it   
                         doesn't work too ...
 }
    }
```

**MainForm**

...

```
public void methodUpdate()
{
 Call.Enabled = true;
}
```

but when I have another button in main form and in method click I have methodUpdate() all work well;

```
button click method in MainForm
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           methodUpdate(); //this is working well

        }
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code?  It sounds like it's not entering your if block at all... can you verify that it is?

Comment: Yes, as Roryap queried, have you stepped through each line of code? I would also suspect that this isn't hitting your `if` statement, either.

Comment: You're creating a new form. Is that the one that's actually displayed? Are you doing those modifications from the UI thread? If so, you might be blocking the UI thread and thus preventing it from changing the button state. If not, you're getting an exception when trying to modify a UI control from a different thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to put your MainForm into the Network Class through the constructor?

In your Network Class:

```
public class Network
{
  private MainForm _frm; 
  public Network(MainForm frm)
  {
    _frm = frm;
  }
  .
  .
  .
    if(isNetwork == true)
    {
      _frm.Call.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

When instantiating an Network-object in your MainForm you call something like that:

```
public Network myNetwork = new Network(this);
```